# embedded views lotus notes horizontal scroll bar

Tags: view, lotus

I have an interesting embedded view issue in lotus notes. I have the view embedded into a table cell and have turned off scrolling and extend last column options and the scroll bars don't display, everything looks good.
But as soon as I check the display actions option the horizontal scroll bar scows. I only have one button. Is there anything I can do to hide the scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can show or hide only both the scrollbars at once. Impossible to set a property for only one scrollbar.